# "Strikes me a great deal" in a negative way

Tags: expressions

Is it correct to use *"Strikes me a great deal* to connotes a negative feeling?

> The rude behavior of the officer *struck me a great deal*. I didn't expect this from a professional person.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't have too much of a problem with that sentence. I'd interpret it to mean that the officer's behavior had an impact on you, and the officer's rudeness was very noticeable.

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/strike) meaning #9 says that *strike* means:

> to affect or cause to affect deeply, suddenly, or radically

That said, the word is often used in a construct like *struck me as* __.  So, perhaps one of these might be an improved way to convey your sentiments:

> - The officer's behavior struck me as rude.
> - The officer's rude behavior struck me as highly unprofessional.
> - The officer's unexpected rudeness struck me as very unprofessional.

but those changes would be mere suggestions to consider; you could opt to leave your sentence as is.

Comment: +1 Best unofficial answer; very clear and on-topic to what OP was asking.

Comment: @Souta, by “unofficial” do you refer to J.R.'s phrases “I don't have too much of a problem” and “I'd interpret it to mean”? If so, *informal* or *offhand* or *slapdash* (in ascending severity) might be more appropriate than *unofficial*.

Comment: @jwpat7 I meant 'unofficial' as in, there hasn't been an answer picked yet! If anything, I would love J.R.'s answer to be picked because it is very on-topic and it decisively answers OP's question. It is still the best answer as of yet. (imo)

Comment: For the record, although I appreciate Souta's upvote, I do think it'd be better to just let Noah (the O.P.) decide which answer should be picked. @jwpat7: Thanks for the chuckle at "slapdash" :^)

Comment: I was never intending to make OP's decision. I was asked what I meant by 'unofficial', and I answered enthusiastically. ^-^

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are trying to emphasize the *startling* quality of the rude behavior. I would suggest

> The rude behavior of the officer was **striking**. I didn't expect this from a professional person.

[American Heritage](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/striking) defines striking as

> Arresting the attention and producing a vivid impression on the sight or the mind.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *[appalled](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/appalled)* is the word you are looking for:-

> offended or shocked very much by something, because it is extremely
>   unpleasant or bad